# Servlet c:url analog

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I deploy my app as war file, and after success deploying it have `%SERVER%/%APP_NAME%/%RES%` url, `c:url` JSTL tag generates `/%APP_NAME%/%RES%`.

How to get same path in servlet?

Comment: So you never explored the available `getXxx()` methods of `HttpServletRequest` out of curiousity?

Comment: @BalusC you hint to `getContextPath() + part`. I see him, just I think have method like `encode(String part)`.